# The Rows Holding the Group-wise Minimun of a Certain Column, but using an additional condition

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

From this dataset:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM document_signature;
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
| id | document_id | employee_id | user_id | order | status    |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
|  1 |           1 |           2 |    NULL |     0 | SIGNED    |
|  2 |           1 |           3 |    NULL |     1 | NOTSIGNED |
|  3 |           1 |           4 |    NULL |     1 | NOTSIGNED |
|  4 |           2 |           3 |    NULL |     0 | NOTSIGNED |
|  5 |           3 |        NULL |       1 |     0 | SIGNED    |
|  6 |           3 |           1 |    NULL |     0 | NOTSIGNED |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to find the rows that have the minimun `order`, but only from those whose status is `NOTSIGNED`, even if there is more than one for each `document_id`

Using this query:

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM document_signature s
WHERE `order` =
      (SELECT MIN(s2.`order`)
       FROM document_signature s2
       WHERE s.document_id = s2.document_id
         AND s2.status = 'NOTSIGNED');
```

These are the results I'm getting:

```sql
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
| id | document_id | employee_id | user_id | order | status    |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
|  2 |           1 |           3 |    NULL |     1 | NOTSIGNED |
|  3 |           1 |           4 |    NULL |     1 | NOTSIGNED |
|  4 |           2 |           3 |    NULL |     0 | NOTSIGNED |
|  5 |           3 |        NULL |       1 |     0 | SIGNED    |
|  6 |           3 |           1 |    NULL |     0 | NOTSIGNED |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My question is: Why is there a row with `status` `SIGNED` in the resultset, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, both `document_id=3` have different `status`, they have the same `order` value. Therefore, your `MIN()` result is actually true for both `status`. The quick way workaround here is to add another `status='NOSIGNED'` condition like so:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM document_signature s
WHERE `order` =
      (SELECT MIN(s2.`order`)
       FROM document_signature s2
       WHERE s.document_id = s2.document_id
         AND s2.status = 'NOTSIGNED')
  AND s.status='NOTSIGNED'; /*add here*/
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LRLORkOt)

There is actually more than one way to do this on MySQL v8+, here is one:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(SELECT *,
       MIN(`order`) OVER (PARTITION BY document_id) AS min_ord
   FROM document_signature
  WHERE status='NOTSIGNED') s
WHERE s.`order`=s.min_ord;
```

On your current sample data, this may look no different but let's say if we add two more rows in the table:

```
INSERT INTO `document_signature` VALUES
(7,1,3,NULL,2,'NOTSIGNED'),
(8,2,4,NULL,2,'NOTSIGNED');
```

it will become like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
| id | document_id | employee_id | user_id | order | status    |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
|  1 |           1 |           2 |    NULL |     0 | SIGNED    |
|  2 |           1 |           3 |    NULL |     1 | NOTSIGNED |
|  3 |           1 |           4 |    NULL |     1 | NOTSIGNED |
|  4 |           2 |           3 |    NULL |     0 | NOTSIGNED |
|  5 |           3 |        NULL |       1 |     0 | SIGNED    |
|  6 |           3 |           1 |    NULL |     0 | NOTSIGNED |
|  7 |           1 |           3 |    NULL |     2 | NOTSIGNED |
|  8 |           2 |           4 |    NULL |     2 | NOTSIGNED |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+
```

Then, when you run the subquery of:

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(`order`) OVER (PARTITION BY document_id) AS min_ord
   FROM document_signature
  WHERE status='NOTSIGNED'
```

you'll get this result:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+---------+
| id | document_id | employee_id | user_id | order | status    | min_ord |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+---------+
|  2 |           1 |           3 |    NULL |     1 | NOTSIGNED |    1    |
|  3 |           1 |           4 |    NULL |     1 | NOTSIGNED |    1    |
|  4 |           2 |           3 |    NULL |     0 | NOTSIGNED |    0    |
|  6 |           3 |           1 |    NULL |     0 | NOTSIGNED |    0    |
|  7 |           1 |           3 |    NULL |     2 | NOTSIGNED |    1    |
|  8 |           2 |           4 |    NULL |     2 | NOTSIGNED |    0    |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+---------+
```

Notice that for `id = 7 & 8`, the value in `min_ord` is not the same as their `order` value. That's when you make that query as derived table and do the `WHERE s.order=s.min_ord` comparison.

[There's another example in this fiddle using cte](https://dbfiddle.uk/2opGOaEa)

Comment: yes you are right, sorry I totally forgot to say that I also came up with this workaround, but my first thought about it was: "Man this looks weird, and it's probably inefficient". I'm obviously not an SQL guru and I might be wrong about that performance assessment. Thanks for your answer, I think I'll stick to this solution for the time being.

Comment: I can think of another way with just a single `status='NOTSIGNED'` condition, but that will work only if you have MySQL v8+.

Comment: Yes! I'm using MySQL v8

Comment: Thanks! This is working flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query even if you are using MySQL v4 :
**Edit1:**

```
SELECT d.* FROM document_signature AS d, (
  SELECT id AS min_id, MIN(`order`) AS min_o FROM document_signature WHERE `status` = 'NOTSIGNED' GROUP BY document_id
) AS t WHERE d.id = t.min_id and d.`order`= t.min_o
```

Comment: What OP wants is to get `MIN(order)` for each `document_id` where the `status='NOTSIGNED'`. This will only work for a single `MIN()` value regardless of `document_id`.

Comment: @OP you are right, edited to word for each document_id.